# How to pass fastboot USB device to VirtualBox Windows VM from ArchLinux?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, usb, virtualbox, android

I have a Xiaomi android phone and I want to unlock its bootloader. The official way is using a Windows tool, so I booted up my Windows VM and tried to pass the USB device form the devices menu, but it says `<no devices available>`. Arch registers the device just fine and `fastboot devices` returns the device ID just fine. Though running `lsusb` gives the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1e7d:2dbe ROCCAT 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2516:0011 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see the device doesn't have a name, and yes the phone is the nameless device, I checked. So could that be the problem that I can't pass it through to Vbox or is it the fact that it's a fastboot device and not a regular mass storage device. Is there a way to get around the issue whatever causes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always I found the solution just after asking. I actually knew this one, just forgot to do it. One has to be in the `vboxusers` group to get access to usb devices. It's as simple as running

`sudo gpasswd -a <user> vboxusers`

in a terminal. For Ubuntu I think it's

`sudo useradd vboxusers`